# How to create a dataset in matlab with random values except for a specific area?

Tags: matlab

I have attached a sample image with explains the requirement.

I have a 16x16 matrix or random values (1-1000) generated by `randi(1000, 16, 16)`

Now I add a 4x4 matrix of same number (eg. 80) somewhere in the 16x16 matrix.

How to I make the large numbers (1-1000) to deviate to my new block of 80s so that the values near 4x4 bock have values closer to 80?
[image]

*PS. 500 near the small matrix should have been ~100 (my mistake)*

Comment: Values closer to 80? You want to say mean value?  I see in your drawing that 500 is closer to the non-random 80 than 85. Can you be more specific?

Comment: That 500 should have been ~100. Sorry. What I mean is to make numbers around a small matrix to deviate to its value. eg. 550->384->104->80->80->80<-105<-240<-364<-476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a weighted average.

- Take a random number `x` and take `80`.
- If you are in the small matrix, the weight of `80` is `1` and the weight of `x` is `0`.
- The further you get from the small matrix, the smaller the weight of `80` and the larger the weight of `x`.